# Which test to perform?

Tags: statistical-significance, biostatistics

**Design:**
We tested mixtures of 12 varieties of species A with species B in multiple growing seasons using an RCBD (Randomized Complete Block Design). The content of species B in the mixture was consistently 15%. After harvesting, we determined the proportion of each species' seeds in the harvested sample.

**Hypothesis:**
Our basic hypothesis is that there would be a variation among the varieties in species A and a more competitive variety of species A would lower the proportion of species B in the harvested grains. Species B is a model weed species, and this is one of the study approaches to assess weed competitiveness variations among the varieties of the selected species A.

**General analysis:**
Lmer analysis revealed no significant differences among the harvested samples regarding the content of species B in the sample, however there was a interaction of variety and year and i will need to interpret the results of the post-hoc tests separately for each growing season. Great.

Model:

```r
(share_of_species_B in the yield ~ variety_of_species_A * YEAR + 
         (1 | BLOCK) + (1 | BLOCK:YEAR)
```

**Question:**
My current idea is to compare the yield proportion of species B to the starting share value of species B (15%), for each variety of species A. I want to see which variety differed significantly compared to the starting value, not only which varieties differed among each other. Sort of Control vs response test, however here there are no variances within the control (constant 15 % starting proportion). Does this make any sense to test? How to approach this analysis? Maybe it's a Monday thing, but I cannot figure this one out.

Comment: It's not clear to me how your blocks are defined, how many observations you have for each variety of A (in order to test significance for a given variety, you'd need to somehow estimate "within variety" variance of the outcome), and what is known about the effect of year from a subject matter perspective (does it make sense to assume independence between years apart from a year effect?).